# How to capture mouse events on an arbitrary QWidget?

Tags: qt, events, pyqt, pyside

I'm building a GUI with `Python` and `Qt`. The standard widgets are quite useful and work out of the box. However, I have some ideas about mouse gestures. More precisely: a button or label or text that, after being clicked and the mouse button held pressed, moving the mouse around has special effects.

What is necessary to add mouse support for the following events

- mouse clicked over widget A while it was visible
- mouse moved to x, y (at real time)
- mouse released

to an arbitrary widget?

---

Right now I am trying to do this by class `A`, which inherits `QAbstractItemView` and owns a `QWidget`. However, nothing works AND

> NotImplementedError: QAbstractItemView.verticalOffset() is abstract and must be overridden

Comment: QAbstractItemView is, well, **abstract** You have to implement all pure virtual methods to instantiate it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QAbstractItemView` is not helpful for your task.

You can install event filter on an arbitrary widget using `installEventFilter`. Your filter class must be inherited from QObject. The documentation contains some useful examples. See [QObject::installEventFilter](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter). If you want to install filter on all widgets at once, you can install it for `QApplication` instance.

Another option is to subclass `QWidget` (or any other QWidget-derived class) and reimplement its `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` virtual functions.

Comment: I just inherited QWidget in A, and am now happily using mousePressEvent() to get mouse information. Not sure if this is as good as your answer, though :(

Comment: It's good solution if creating new class inherited from QWidget is convenient for you. However, my solution doesn't require you to create new classes for each widget. It can be more convenient in some cases.